# Beginner Oracle APEX - Using ITEMS for a query

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

So I'm trying to select some names from a table where their set dates are between two dates that I enter via keyboard.

If it was for a single input, where I only use something like (`:x`) in the region source, I could just create a Text Field Item X where I enter something and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

What if I need multiple inputs? like (`:x`) and (`:y`).
Upon creating 2 items and entering their values nothing happens when I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

The Region Source is this:

```
SELECT * FROM TOYS WHERE SALE_DATE BETWEEN upper(:x) AND upper(:y);
```

What am I supposed to do in order to enter two inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to initiate an action (submit the page, for example) by changing value, you have to find a property `Submit when Enter pressed` in item's settings and set it to `Yes`. For select lists, the same property is `Page Action on Selection`, and desired value for it - `Submit Page`.
Or, you can just create a button. Button's action by default is also "submit page".